# remove single quotes followed by whitespace from a string using trim

Tags: php

I am trying to remove whitespace and single quotes from a string.

```
$string = "'DZ;Algeria;The People's Democratic Republic of Algeria;Algerian'  ";
echo trim($string,"'");
```

In the above string I want to remove single quotes from both ends, but `trim` only removes the left single quote. The right side single quote remains after trimming.

The output is:

> DZ;Algeria;The People's Democratic Republic of Algeria;Algerian'

But I want this:

> DZ;Algeria;The People's Democratic Republic of Algeria;Algerian

Comment: Define: whitespace.  Or rather are these spaces as from using say a spacebar, or could they be tabs etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) twice. Firstly, trim the string to remove leading and trailing spaces; and then trim again to remove leading and trailing single quotes (after removal of leading/trailing spaces)

```
$string = "'DZ;Algeria;The People's Democratic Republic of Algeria;Algerian'  ";
echo trim(trim($string),"'");
```

**Demo**: https://3v4l.org/0rsXN

Comment: why two trims bro

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan check the explanation please

Comment: There is an advantage to this method over the single call `trim($string,"' ")`, in that it takes care of whitespace that isn't just a _space_.  However order matters with this one.  Both fine with the OP's input.  The alternative is to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53178679/3392762 which is explicitly verbose if other whitespace may be leading or trailing.  Results could be different on different input strings, they are not functionally identical.

Answer (score 4):

Add a space to the list of characters to trim on.

```
echo trim($string,"' ");
```

https://3v4l.org/CkbZP

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for trim on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) states that the second parameter:

> **character_mask**
>
> Optionally, the stripped characters can also be specified using the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.

by default, the character mask contains whitespace characters:

> - " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
> - "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> - "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> - "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> - "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> - "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

If you want to trim single quotes and also the spaces before and after them, you can add the single quote to that list:

```
$string = "'DZ;Algeria;The People's Democratic Republic of Algeria;Algerian'  ";
echo trim($string,"' \t\n\r\0\x0B");
```

Otherwise, the whitespace characters **are considered non-trimmable** and the quote won't be removed.

If you need to keep the spaces, you will need to use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a regular expression.